# Query to get large numbers or specific string from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Part 1:

I have data like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  MyString NVARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
 ('str1 0319100004919000913 str2 str3 str4 str5 # 42')
,('str1 #127/322410. str2 str3 25.05.2021 str4 12.31.2021 str4.4 str4.1 str6.93; str7: 213583300014958330100100010000000000.')
,('str1 str2 # 7  (str3. #0119200000120014883)')
,('str1 # 156 str2 05.31.2012; 0134200000120005404|NULL')
,('str1 str2 str3 #0321200014120000733 str4')
,('str1 str2 str3 07.07.2021 (RD-GK-320-21-LS-07-12-2021-DTR232) str4.4 str4.1 str6.93') --specific string begins with RD-...
,('str1 str2 str3 30.06.2021 (RD-GK-319-21-LS-12-31-2021-DTR67)str4.4str4.1str6.er67')
,('str1 # IMZ-2021-010906. str2 str3 30.08.2021 str 31.12.2021 str5. str4'); --specific string begins with IMZ-...
```

The output I expect is

large number:

```
 1. 0319100004919000913
 2. 213583300014958330100100010000000000
 3. 0119200000120014883
 4. 0134200000120005404
 5. 0321200014120000733
```

specific string:

```
 1. RD-GK-320-21-LS-07-12-2021-DTR232
 2. RD-GK-319-21-LS-12-31-2021-DTR67
 3. IMZ-2021-010906
```

Part 2:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(prodID INT, MyString NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 (1, 'str1 #127 str2 07.02.12 str2 (1- 0387200009121002533, 2- 0387200009121002560)')
,(2, 'str1 # 156 str2 31.05.2012str2; 1) 0121200002121000373; 2) 0134200005921000161')
,(3, 'str1 #1746 str2 05.09.19 str2 (1- str24. str22, 2- 0142200001321000810, 3- 0365100000921001253)|NULL')
,(4, 'str1 #1746 str2 05.09.19 str2 (1,2- str2. str2,str2; 3- 0817200000320013050, 4- 0308200003021000147)')
,(5, 'str1 #1746 str2 от 05.09.19 str2 (1- 0809500000321002170, 2- 0108200000121000197, 3- 0860200000821006486)')
,(6, 'str1 #1817 str2 03.04.20 str2 (1- 0176200005521001714, 2- 0380200000121005479)|NULL')
,(7, 'str1 #1817 str2 03.04.20 str2 (1- 32110289270, 2- 32110848602, 3- 32110882257, 4,5- 32110018979, 6- 32110031431)|NULL');
-- DDL and sample data population, end
```

for now the output is (if we are using answer of part 1)

[image: 1. List item]

The output I expect is

[image]

And I want to implement it in SQL Server (Version: 2017 and above)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Sql server is very poor to do string logic. why don't you do it on AP?

Comment: Define precisely "large number". At what point (length?) does a series of numeric characters qualify as "large" for inclusion in your resultset? Same question for you "specific string". What "patterns" qualify for inclusion? The contents of a column contain multiple qualifying values, what happens? If you assume that cannot happen, then state that assumption explicitly. And yes - tsql is a poor choice for such goals.

Comment: Aside... when dealing with `nchar` and `nvarchar` values get in the habit of using National character literals so as to avoid the loss of Unicode characters that don't exist in your database's default collation. e.g.: compare the outputs from `select N'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ', 'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ'`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, thanks for your comment, I've added DDL & Version of SQL Server

Comment: @SMor, large number - series of numeric characters >9, specific string - yes, the contents of a column contain multiple qualifying values, for example, RD-..., IMS-... etc. What technology or programming language do you recommend for this task?

Comment: Gosh this is just awful. And the explanation isn't very clear. You say you want to find numbers sequences longer than 9. But then you also have this stuff about specific strings. What is that all about? Are those values static or do they follow some pattern of some sort?

Comment: I kind of see these "specific strings" that you are talking about but they don't even have a consistent end to them. In your examples two of them end with ) and the other ends with a period. There is so much ambiguity in your data that no language is going to be easy to parse this. My guess is the real data is even worse and you will need a zillion more rules to capture all the outliers.

Comment: @SeanLange, not static, they follow some pattern from our clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(MyString NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 ('str1 0319100004919000913 str2 str3 str4 str5 # 42')
,('str1 #127/322410. str2 str3 25.05.2021 str4 12.31.2021 str4.4 str4.1 str6.93; str7: 213583300014958330100100010000000000.')
,('str1 str2 # 7  (str3. #0119200000120014883)')
,('str1 # 156 str2 05.31.2012; 0134200000120005404|NULL')
,('str1 str2 str3 #0321200014120000733 str4')
,('str1 str2 str3 07.07.2021 (RD-GK-320-21-LS-07-12-2021-DTR232) str4.4 str4.1 str6.93') --specific string begins with RD-...
,('str1 str2 str3 30.06.2021 (RD-GK-319-21-LS-12-31-2021-DTR67)str4.4str4.1str6.er67')
,('str1 # IMZ-2021-010906. str2 str3 30.08.2021 str 31.12.2021 str5. str4'); --specific string begins with IMZ-...
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @filter VARCHAR(10) = '#|.(),';

SELECT value 
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TRANSLATE(MyString, @filter, SPACE(LEN(@filter))), SPACE(1))
WHERE TRY_CAST(value AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL
    AND LEN(value) > 9;

SELECT value 
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TRANSLATE(MyString, @filter, SPACE(LEN(@filter))), SPACE(1))
WHERE LEFT(value, 3) IN ('RD-', 'IMZ');
```

**Output #1**

```
+--------------------------------------+
|                value                 |
+--------------------------------------+
|                  0319100004919000913 |
| 213583300014958330100100010000000000 |
|                  0119200000120014883 |
|                  0134200000120005404 |
|                  0321200014120000733 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

**Output #2**

```
+-----------------------------------+
|               value               |
+-----------------------------------+
| RD-GK-320-21-LS-07-12-2021-DTR232 |
| RD-GK-319-21-LS-12-31-2021-DTR67  |
| IMZ-2021-010906                   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, it is work for SQL Server 2017. I did not take into account the following point. I have divided my question into 2 parts, part 1 works well, do you have any idea about part 2?

Comment: Just add a comma to the filter variable: `DECLARE @filter VARCHAR(10) = '#|.(),';`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot